# Can I refight Ring Fit Adventure's final boss?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I beat the final boss recently. It was a fun and intense workout, and I'd like to be able to play it again in the future. Is there a way to refight it without starting the game over, or is it a one-time event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot, according to dafipp on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RingFitAdventure/comments/g1hjoc/can_you_ever_replay_the_previous_dragaux_fights/):

> I wasn't sure so I just went back and checked...No, the original Dragaux fights do not open back up after completing the first run thru of the game.

There is however an option to

> start a New Game+ or New Game++, and you will encounter him there again

Answer (score 2):

It seems that that the answer from Mathias is no longer correct. You definitely can refight the final boss again (I've tested it myself).

Since it seems that not everybody can I have the following 3 hypotheses.

- You need to complete all stages for each of the 23 worlds.
- You need to complete all stages and secondary missions for each of the 23 worlds.
- You need to get the most recent update.

I remember that when I finish the game the first time I saw the exclamation flag on the final boss when I got back. That leads me to think that the first hypothesis is the correct one.

Comment: I have finished my second run and I haven't even completed and I can re-fight the final boss which lead me to think that it was just a matter of updating the game

Comment: Sadly it appears you can't skip dialogs, credits, and summary, which alltogether take more time tgan boss fight. .